# FBLoginView and FBSession not found in current Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am building an app with Facebook integration. I downloaded the latest version of Facebook SDK from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

I got the login/logout working following the instructions on Facebook website.

Now I want to customize the Login button as well as check if the user has already logged in then the app should load the home screen on startup. For this I looked up for code online and most of them use `FBLoginView` and `FBSession` which is not available in the SDK I downloaded.

I also tried looking for `FacebookSDKResource.bundle` as suggested online, but even this is not available in the SDK.

Can anyone suggest a way to use `FBLoginView` and `FBSession` or any alternative to these classes for the latest SDK?

How do I make `custom login button` and `check if the user has logged in`?

Answer (score 0):

to check if user is logged in im currently doing next

```
if ([FBSDKProfile currentProfile]) {
   NSLog("is logged in");
}
```

Using FBSDKCoreKit.framework

I don't know if there is another way...

Of course, first i use FBSDKLoginManager to perform login...

To make a custom button for login, simply make a UIButton with a IBAction to manage the login...

Answer (score 0):

This is the library you're looking for. It's not the most up to date but has the classes you mentioned.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk